# Open any kind of file with an uwp app (without file association)

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

I am making a simple uwp text editor app. I want the app to open any kind of file even without file associations declared since there are many text files which don't have known extension in the os. Is there any way I can modify the registry to have my app available in Open-With list like notepad so user can open that file with my app from the file explorer itself??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows 10 2004 (build 19041) microsoft introduced `uap10:FileType` attribute in package manifest and by providing `*` as the value the app is available in open with menu of all types of files. To use this just add the following code to your manifest:

```
xmlns:uap10="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/10"
...
<uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
  <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name="anyfile">
    <uap:Logo>Assets\mylogo.png</uap:Logo>
    <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
      <uap:FileType>.txt</uap:FileType>
      <uap10:FileType>*</uap10:FileType>
    </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
  </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
</uap:Extension>
```

This only works for Windows 10 build 19041 and above. The additional `uap:FileType` is necessary if app targets minimum version below 19041 to pass manifest validation, otherwise it can be omitted.

Comment: I receive an error `Reason: Element '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/10}FileType' is unexpected according to content model of parent element '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10}SupportedFileTypes'` even though I set `<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.14393.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.19041.0" />`. What seems to be an issue? Can you show a working full example?

Comment: Sure. How can I send it to you?

Comment: Here is the link to a zip file containing both original working and new NOT working manifest: https://emeditor.blob.core.windows.net/beta/appxmanifest.zip Thank you.

Comment: In my sample, `uap10:FileType` is actually inside `uap:SupportedFileTypes`. However, I've removed `uap2:SupportedVerbs`, and I've made it exactly as your snippet, but it still won't compile. Please see: 
https://emeditor.blob.core.windows.net/beta/manifest2.zip

Comment: If you can provide me your full working sample (NOT snippet), I might be able to figure out what the issue is. I want to know exactly what you wrote outside your `uap:Extension` tag. Can you provide a link to your full sample?

Comment: This is a desktop bridge application, and `FileType` in manifest is required to register. So this technique doesn't work for a desktop bridge apps?

Comment: Well, actually, I've figured out the issue. The **PATH** environment should include `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64`. Any older version paths to `Windows Kits` fail to compile. After I set the PATH correctly, the error disappeared. Thanks for your tips.

Answer (score 1):

Great question, but I'm afraid you could not modify the registry to make the app available in Open-With list  even without file associations declared within UWP  app. And file association is only way to make the app could [handle the file activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-file-activation). Both Windows desktop applications and Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps can register to be a default file handler. If you do want this feature please feel free post your requirement with windows feed back hub app.

Comment: I am working on a desktop extension by which user can open unsupported file extensions. The two method I can see for redirecting the activation is launching via protocol or from command line. When I pass the file path via commandline it works for all types of files except bat file, and the protocol activation for some reason doesn't work. Any solution to this??

Comment: protocol activation for some reason doesn't work？ Could you share the detail about the protocol or provide us a [mcve].

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/arunjeetsingh/SampleCode/tree/master/WPFAppLaunchingUniversalApp) is an example.

Comment: Do you means you could not launch uwp app from wpf client?

Comment: Please try to remove `LauncherOptions` from `LaunchUriAsync` method.

Comment: I tried again it seems this works from wpf app but doesn't work in winform. In winform it doesn't even error out just nothing happens, any reason why that happens?

Comment: That's interesting, could add try catch block to get the exception?

Comment: The problem is there is no exception, the execution just stops at the `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync` line.

Comment: Have you add Await key word?

Comment: Yes I have added await.

Comment: It is possible now with Windows 10 2004 (build 19041) and above, check my answer for more.

Comment: Ok, I will check it, I found you have post the answer, good job.