# UWP application unable to access USB drive even though permissions are set

Tags: c#, uwp, access-denied, removable-storage

I am working on an app that is responsible for formatting a USB drive and prepare it for further use on an embedded system.

I am formatting the drive using the following method that I found on stack overflow (unfortunately I did not save the link. I'll post it there if I find it again)

```cs
public static bool FormatUSB(string driveLetter, string fileSystem = "FAT32", bool quickFormat = true,
                                   int clusterSize = 4096, string label = "USB_0000", bool enableCompression = false)
        {
            //add logic to format Usb drive
            //verify conditions for the letter format: driveLetter[0] must be letter. driveLetter[1] must be ":" and all the characters mustn't be more than 2
            if (driveLetter.Length != 2 || driveLetter[1] != ':' || !char.IsLetter(driveLetter[0]))
                return false;

            //query and format given drive 
            //best option is to use ManagementObjectSearcher

            var files = Directory.GetFiles(driveLetter);
            var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(driveLetter);

            foreach (var item in files)
            {
                try
                {
                    File.Delete(item);
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }
                catch (IOException) { }
            }

            foreach (var item in directories)
            {
                try
                {
                    Directory.Delete(item);
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }
                catch (IOException) { }
            }

            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"select * from Win32_Volume WHERE DriveLetter = '" + driveLetter + "'");
            foreach (ManagementObject vi in searcher.Get())
            {
                try
                {
                    var completed = false;
                    var watcher = new ManagementOperationObserver();

                    watcher.Completed += (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("USB format completed " + args.Status);
                        completed = true;
                    };
                    watcher.Progress += (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("USB format in progress " + args.Current);
                    };

                    vi.InvokeMethod(watcher, "Format", new object[] { fileSystem, quickFormat, clusterSize, label, enableCompression });

                    while (!completed) { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); }


                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

I also added all the capabilities that should be required (I think) in order to access a removable drive in my manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  xmlns:iot="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap iot">

  <Identity
    Name="7b9becad-6afd-4872-bcb7-7f414c098edf"
    Publisher="CN=vitto"
    Version="1.0.0.0" />

  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="7b9becad-6afd-4872-bcb7-7f414c098edf" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"/>

  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>DiskMakerApp</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>vitto</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>

  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
  </Dependencies>

  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate"/>
  </Resources>

  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App"
      Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
      EntryPoint="DiskMakerApp.App">
      <uap:VisualElements
        DisplayName="DiskMakerApp"
        Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png"
        Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png"
        Description="DiskMakerApp"
        BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png"/>
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>

  <Capabilities>
      <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
      <rescap:Capability Name="appCaptureSettings" />
      <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <uap:Capability Name="removableStorage" />
      <iot:Capability Name="systemManagement"/>
      <DeviceCapability Name="usb"/>
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

And also allowed access to the file system in Window's settings page:
[image]

But I am still getting:
[image]

I am wondering if I am missing anything. Is there a way I could run the app as an administrator^ Would that solve the issue? (In any case, only admins would be able to run that app in a real life scenario)

Comment: Build the executable for the app, and then run as admin like you said - that should confirm if it's an admin rights issue

Comment: Also, can you access the USB drive normally through Explorer to rule out any misc. issues with the drive?

Comment: I ran VS as admin, which should run the app with admin rights and still got the error) and yes I can access the drive through the explorer. Trying to run the .exe directly from the build folder won't do anything though

Comment: Add a File Type Association declaration for * - does that work?

Comment: Do you mean adding this section? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61059755/open-any-kind-of-file-with-an-uwp-app-without-file-association Where should I add that extensions section in the manifest?

Comment: Try within Package in an `<Extensions>` block

Comment: adding it in Extension block seems like it wants to work, but I get a compile error saying that Extensions block cannot contain <uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">

Comment: Sorry - add the `Extensions` block inside `Applications` as opposed to `Package`

Comment: Yup you are right according to the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap-filetypeassociation! No more errors but still denied

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237763/discussion-between-ermiya-eskandary-and-vitonimal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UWP application unable to access USB drive even though permissions are set

[`Directory.GetFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-5.0) can't not use to access file with path in UWP platform. And you can only use **Windows Storage API** to access file with path (enable [broadFileSystemAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) ), by the way, [`System.Management Namespace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) is not work for UWP platform, and if you want to format USB device within UWP app, please use desktop extension to process. for more please refer stefan' blog **UWP with Desktop Extension**